# ubuntu 12.10 netbeans 7.2

Tags: ubuntu-12.10

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and Netbeans IDE 7.2 and this was all working fine until yesterday.
Now i'm not able to run netbeans as normal user, only as administrator.
As normal user the program launches but notting appears on screan.

Comment: if you are launching netbean, what process runs? (ps -ef | grep netbeans)

Answer (score 1):

**If you are confident that, with the account "superadmin" the netbeans working properly**

It seems proper affirm that your user workspace is corrupted.

You can re-create a new workspace for user:

```
$  rm -rfv /home/userdir/.netbeans
```

*Attention with this command you will lose information group projects and open projects. But do not lose, project data, you should just reopen them or create new groups.*

Or you can move your workspace like this:

```
$ /path/to/netbeans/bin/netbeans -userdir /path/to/new/userdir
```

Or if you prefer to read up on what happened can be found in the corresponding logs directory:

> /home/userdir/.netbeans/7.2/var/log

so you can decide if you can solve the problem in another way, without recreating your workspace.

It is also possible that for some strange reason, the user has lost the execute permissions on some netbeans folder.

Comment: I removed the directory. Now it seems to work fine.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: man, thank you for accepting the answer :) [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)